# Adding key/value Pairs results in keys with null values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm having an issue that the dictionary `timeStamps` changes all the values to `null`. The keys are all fine, even if I switch what was a key to a value and vice versa. No matter the order, the values end up as `null` and the keys end up exactly as they should.

Here's the code. It's an xml parser. It is building a dictionary that has an array of codes for keys and an array of timestamps for values. The keys and values are parallel arrays representing categories.

All variables are allocated and initiated elsewhere. This imports the header file that has all of these variables as properties. `@property (strong, nonatomic) Type variableName;` then in the main file it has the line `@synthesize variableName`. Also, it has `variableName = [[Type alloc] init];`. Thank you everybody for your help!

```
- (void) didStartElement (elementname is passed as xml tag)
{
    //Tells us if we are in the dance categories
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"categories"])
    {
        isCategory = YES; // Just tells us we're ready to start reading

    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"] && isCategory) 
    {
        onCategory = YES; // 
    }
}


- (void) foundCharacters (currentNodeContent is the info between tags)
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) string;
}


- (void) didEndElement
{
    // if leaving dance categories
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Category End"])
    {
        isCategory = NO; // We've left a category
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"code"] && onCategory)
    {
        Code               = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
        isWaitingForTime   = YES;
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"time"] && isWaitingForTime)
    {
        [runningList       addObject:Code];
        [runningList   addObject:currentNodeContent];

        isWaitingForTime   = NO;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
        Code               = @"";
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"dances"])
    {
        [timeStamps setObject:runningTimeList forKey:runningList];
        [runningTimeList   removeAllObjects];
        [runningList       removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually instantiated the arrays?

Comment: As background, why are you using *arrays* of strings as both your key and value types? Or do you want them just to be strings?

Comment: Since you never actually created the dictionary the calls to fetch values from the dictionary return nil.

Comment: Yes, I instantiated the arrays. I have `Array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` for both arrays. Also, the arrays are filled with many strings, I was trying to give the simplest overview of what I did.

Comment: @MisterMister What Hot Licks is saying is that you don't `alloc/init` the dictionary (at least in the code you posted).

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I have it in my code. Sorry, I should have included it in the posted code

Comment: @MisterMister You are wasting a lot of people's time by not posting the actual code. Update your question with the real code that doesn't work as expected. Include the code that populates the dictionary and the code that gives you the `nil` result. Then people can help you find the cause of the problem.

Comment: You still have not posted any code that inits dictionaryOfArrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you're really asking here, but let's see if any of the following helps.

First consider this method based on your code fragment:

```
- (void) test
{
   NSMutableArray *Array1 = [NSMutableArray new];
   NSMutableArray *Array2 = [NSMutableArray new];

   [Array1 addObject:@"Hello"];
   [Array1 addObject:@"There"];
   [Array2 addObject:@"Hi"];
   [Array2 addObject:@"Welcome"];

   NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfArrays = [NSMutableDictionary new];

   [dictionaryOfArrays setObject:Array2 forKey:Array1];

   // arrays are ordered, use key with elements in different order to show this
   [dictionaryOfArrays setObject:Array2 forKey:@[@"There", @"Hello"]];

   NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dictionaryOfArrays);
}
```

This will output to the console:

```
dictionary: {
        (
        There,
        Hello
    ) =     (
        Hi,
        Welcome
    );
        (
        Hello,
        There
    ) =     (
        Hi,
        Welcome
    );
}
```

The shows that the *key* can be an array - and the order of elements in the array is important.

However do you really want to use arrays as keys? While having the *values* as arrays is common, it is not common for the key to be an array as well.

You say you are getting either `( )` or "null". Well the first of those could be an array with no elements - which is distinct from no array. As to the second, you cannot store `nil` in a `NSDictionary` but if you look up a value for a non-existant key then `nil` is returned - i.e. a `nil` return means a non-existant key.

Finally in case it is relevant, when a key/value pair is added to a dictionary the key is *copied* while the value is simply *referenced*. This means that if you use a mutable object as a key, e.g. a `NSMutableString` instance, then subsequent mutations of the object do not effect the dictionary. However if the value (of the key/value pair) is a mutable object then  a lookup operation returns the exact same object as was inserted, which could have been mutated since insertion.

The code you've added to your question doesn't clarify at all.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: Thanks! That most definitely _was_ relevant. The value is referenced solves my question. Do you know if there's any way to copy the value into the dictionary?

Comment: Solution: `[timeStamps setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:runningTimeList copyItems:YES] forKey:runningList];`

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the arrays and the dictionary.
This should work:

```
NSMutableArray *Array1 = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *Array2 = [NSMutableArray new];

[Array1 addObject:@"Hello"];
[Array2 addObject:@"Hi"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryOfArrays = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[dictionaryOfArrays setObject:Array2 forKey:Array1];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dictionaryOfArrays);
```

If you are planning to store only one object at a time, you don't have to creat arrays in order to do that. You can set the actual NSStrings in this method as it takes any `id` as an object and string as a key.

Otherwise you should use the method `setObjects:forKeys:` instead of this one.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear as to why, if both Array1 and Array2 are _not_ `null`, when I add them to the dictionary, no matter which is the value and which is the key, the value always ends up as null.

Comment: That's probably something with ARC, but it happens often. I have no idea why it releases the value and not the key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting a mutable array as key of a dictionary. The array is copied and then stored into the dictionary. If you do not change the array, `objectForKey:` will always return the value you were seeking for. But if you add any object to it, the array mutates and it isn't anymore equal to the copy stored inside the dictionary.

From the code it seems like you don't need a dictionary at all, you're just using the dictionary to store every result, so you may want to replace `timeStamps` with a `NSMutableSet` or `NSMutableArray`.

**PS**: Also remember to add copies of `runningTimeList`, not the original array. This because  you're not creating the array every time that you end an element, you're just emptying it. This means that all keys point to the same array.

Comment: Sorry, just some clarification: are you saying that if I add the key/value pair to the dictionary, then change the key or value outside of the dictionary, the dictionary changes? Because when I do a NSLog of the dictionary, all the keys come out as they should, but the values are all null. So there is something funky with setting something as the value instead of the key...

Comment: No it doesn't change the value, but when you call objectForKey: it returns nil because the array has been changed from the one you originally stored as key.  You are also emptying runningTimeList everytime instead of recreating another array, so your dictionary is just a bunch of keys pointing to the same object. In this definitely not the case to use a dictionary.